# Ionic app, calling $state.go cause error Function required as first argument! at file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.min.js

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an ionic app that works fine with ionic serve, but when i run it on android device, i get when i click on login form this error

> "Function required as first argument! at file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.min.js",

after debugging i see that this error is fired when changing state,
`$state.go('map'),` 
when i comment this line 
`//$state.go('map')`, no error is happening, the user is logged in successfully. but the crazy thing is the other state are working fine, there is only the state in login that is not working.

Controller:

```
    .controller('HomeCtrl', function ($rootScope, $http, $scope, $state, $stateParams, $ionicPopup, $ionicLoading, $ionicHistory, $timeout, $cordovaOauth, $location, localStorageService, ProfileService) {
        $scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {

          $scope.updateLocation()

          $rootScope.googleProfile = null;
          $rootScope.facebookProfile = null;
          // //console.log('State changed: ', toState)

          $scope.facebook = function() {
            $cordovaOauth.facebook("282650518775396", ["email", "public_profile"], {redirect_uri: "http://localhost/callback"}).then(function(result){
              $scope.displayData(result.access_token);
            }, function(error){
              alert("Error: " + error);
            });
          }

          $scope.displayData = function(access_token) {
            $http.get("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/me", {params: {access_token: access_token, fields: "name,email,id,gender,location,picture", format: "json" }}).then(function(result) {
                // alert("name: " + result.data.name);
                console.log("facebook profile: " + JSON.stringify(result.data));
                ProfileService.facebook(result.data, function(response) {
                  if (! response) {
                    // //console.log('login ou mot de passe incorrect !')
                    localStorageService.set('facebookProfile', result.data);
                    $timeout(function() {
                      $state.go('register');
                    }, 100);
                  } else {
                    $timeout(function () {
                      // console.log('redirect to categories !')
                      $ionicLoading.hide()
                      $ionicHistory.clearCache()
                      $ionicHistory.clearHistory()
                      $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
                        disableBack: true,
                        historyRoot: true
                      })

                      if (ProfileService.profile().type == 1)
                        $state.go('app.map')
                      else
                        $state.go('app.categories')
                    }, 100)
                  }
                });
            }, function(error) {
                alert("Error: " + error);
            });
          }

          if ($location.path() == '/home') {
            if (auth = ProfileService.isAuth()) {
              $ionicLoading.show({
                template: 'Auto connexion...'
              })
              $timeout(function () {
                ProfileService.get(ProfileService.profile().id, function (response) {
                  localStorageService.set('profile', response)
                  $rootScope.profile = response;
                  $ionicHistory.clearCache()
                  $ionicHistory.clearHistory()
                  $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
                    disableBack: true,
                    historyRoot: true
                  })
                  $ionicLoading.hide()

                  if (response.type == 1)
                    $state.go('app.map')
                  else
                    $state.go('app.categories')
                })
              }, 100)
            }
          }
        })

        $scope.user = {}

        $scope.updateLocation = function() {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (pos) {
            $scope.user.lat = pos.coords.latitude
            $scope.user.lng = pos.coords.longitude
            if (auth = ProfileService.isAuth()) {
              ProfileService.updateGeo({
                lat: pos.coords.latitude,
                lng: pos.coords.longitude,
                user_id: auth.id
              }, function(response) {
                console.log(response)
              })
            }
            console.log('location updated', $scope.user)
          }, function (error) {
            console.log('Unable to get location: ' + error.message)
          })
        }

        // login
        $scope.login = function () {
          if ($scope.user.mail && $scope.user.password) {
            // //console.log($scope.user)
            $ionicLoading.show({
              template: 'Chargement...'
            })
            ProfileService.Auth($scope.user, function (response) {
              console.log(response)
              if (! response) {
                // //console.log('login ou mot de passe incorrect !')
                $ionicPopup.alert({
                  template: 'login ou mot de passe incorrect !',
                  title: 'Erreur'
                })
                $ionicLoading.hide()
              } else {
                $timeout(function () {
                  // //console.log('redirect to categories !')
                  $ionicLoading.hide()
                  $ionicHistory.clearCache()
                  $ionicHistory.clearHistory()
                  $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
                    disableBack: true,
                    historyRoot: true
                  })

                  if (ProfileService.profile().type == 1) {
                    // $state.go('app.map')
                     $location.url('app/map')
                    console.log('redirect to map !')
                  }
                  else {
                    // $state.go('app.categories')
                    $location.url('app/categories')
                    console.log('redirect to categories !')
                  }
                }, 100)
              }
            })
          } else {
            $ionicPopup.alert({
              title: 'Champs obligatoires',
              template: 'Tous les champs sont obligatoires!'
            })
          }
        }
      // end login
      })


 .controller('CategoriesCtrl', function ($ionicNativeTransitions, $cordovaGeolocation, $stateParams, $rootScope, $scope, $state, $log, $location, $timeout, $ionicLoading, $ionicPopup, localStorageService, ProfileService, CategoryService, requestService, paymentService, $ionicHistory) {
    $scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
      // //console.log('State changed: ', toState)

      $scope.data = {
        lat: '',
        lng: '',
        destination_lat: '',
        destination_lng: '',
        username: ProfileService.profile().name,
        user_id: ProfileService.profile().id,
        forfait: $stateParams.forfait,
      }

      if ($location.path() == '/app/categories') {
        $ionicLoading.show({
          template: 'Chargement...'
        })

        if (! ProfileService.isAuth()) {
          $state.go('home')
        }

        $scope.getProfile()
        $scope.getCategories(function () {
          $scope.categories = $.map($scope.categories, function(value, index) { 
            return [value]; 
          });
          $timeout(function () {
            $ionicLoading.hide()
          }, 1000)
        })
      } else if ($location.path() == '/app/subcategories/'+$stateParams.category) {
        $scope.getSubCategories(function() {
          $scope.subcategories = $.map($scope.subcategories, function(value, index) { 
            return [value]; 
          });
        })
      } else if ($location.path() == '/app/forfaits/'+$stateParams.subcategory) {
        $scope.getForfaits(function() {
          $scope.forfaits = $.map($scope.forfaits, function(value, index) { 
            return [value]; 
          });
        })
      } else if ($location.path() == '/app/detail_forfait/'+$stateParams.forfait) {
        $scope.getCurrentPosition()
        $scope.getDetailForfait(function() {
          $scope.options = $.map($scope.options, function(value, index) { 
            return [value]; 
          });
        })
      }
    })

    $scope.getProfile = function () {
      ProfileService.get(ProfileService.profile().id, function (response) {
        $rootScope.profile = response
      })
    }

    // $scope.loadCategory = function (id) {
    //   $ionicNativeTransitions.stateGo('app.category', {id: id}, {
    //     'type': 'slide',
    //     'direction': 'up', // 'left|right|up|down', default 'left' (which is like 'next')
    //     'duration': 1500, // in milliseconds (ms), default 400
    //   })
    // }

    $scope.location = {
      formatted_address: ""
    };$scope.destinationlocation = {
      formatted_address: ""
    };
    /*$scope.address = {};*/

    $scope.searchPosition = function(location, type) {
      type = type || null;
      console.log(type)
      console.log(location)
      var geo = new google.maps.Geocoder;
      geo.geocode({'address':location},function(results, status){
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
              var myLatLng = results[0].geometry.location;
              if (type == 'destination') {
                $scope.data.destination_lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                $scope.data.destination_lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                $scope.map.setCenter(myLatLng)
                $scope.destmarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: myLatLng,
                  map: $scope.map
                })
              } else {
                $scope.data.lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                $scope.data.lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                $scope.map.setCenter(myLatLng)
                $scope.marker.setPosition(myLatLng)
              }

              if ($scope.data.lat && $scope.data.lng && $scope.data.destination_lat && $scope.data.destination_lng) {
                var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
                var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

                $scope.map.setCenter(myLatLng)

                var request = {
                   origin: $scope.data.lat+','+$scope.data.lng, 
                   destination: $scope.data.destination_lat+','+$scope.data.destination_lng,
                   travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
                };

                directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
                  if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {

                     // Display the distance:
                     $scope.distance = response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value;
                     $scope.distance = $scope.distance >= 1000 ? $scope.distance/1000 + " Km" : $scope.request.distance + "M"

                     // Display the duration:
                     $scope.duration = moment.duration(response.routes[0].legs[0].duration.value,"seconds").format("h [hrs], m [min]");

                     directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                     directionsDisplay.setMap($scope.map);
                  }
               });
              }
          } else {
              alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
          }
      });
    }

    $scope.initMap = function () {
      console.log($scope.data)
      var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(43.07493, -89.381388)

      var mapOptions = {
        center: myLatlng,
        zoom: 16,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      }

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
        mapOptions)

      if ($scope.data.lat && $scope.data.lng) {
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng($scope.data.lat , $scope.data.lng)

        $.get('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='+$scope.data.lat+','+$scope.data.lng+'&sensor=false', function(data) {
          if (data.status == 'OK') {
            $scope.location.formatted_address = data.results[0].formatted_address;
          };
        });

        map.setCenter(myLatlng)

        $scope.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatlng,
          map: map
        })
      }

      $scope.map = map
    }

    $scope.disable_after_send = false

    $scope.makeRequest = function () {
      var error = false;

      if ($scope.category == 520) {
        if ($scope.data.destination_lat == '' && $scope.data.destination_lng == '') {
          error = true;
          $ionicPopup.alert({
            title: 'Info',
            template: 'Vous devez choisir une destination'
          });
        }
      }

      if ( ! error) {
        $ionicPopup.show({
           title: 'Confirmation',
           template: "Vous allez être débiter de "+$scope.forfait.price+" €",
           buttons: [
            {
              text: 'Annuler',
            },
            {
              text: 'Confirmer',
              type: 'button-positive',
              onTap: function(e) {
                $ionicLoading.show({
                  template: 'Chargement...'
                });
                $scope.data.price = $scope.forfait.price;
                $scope.data.options = JSON.stringify($scope.selected_options);
                $scope.disable_after_send = true;

                requestService.send($scope.data, function (response) {
                  console.log('response', response)
                  $scope.disable_after_send = false
                  if (response.send_to) {
                    $ionicPopup.alert({
                      template: "Votre demande à été envoyée - en attente d'un profesionnel",
                      title: 'Demande envoyée'
                    })

                    $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
                      disableBack: true
                    })

                    $state.go('app.request', { request: response.request_id })
                  } else {
                    $ionicLoading.hide();
                    $ionicPopup.alert({
                      template: "Aucun pro n'est disponible actuellement dans votre zone !",
                      title: "Demande non envoyée"
                    })
                  }
                })
              }
            },
            {
              text: 'Changer carte de paiement',
              type: 'button-assertive',
              onTap: function(e) {
                $state.go('app.card', { action: 'change'});
              }
            }
           ]
         });
      }

       /*confirmPopup.then(function(res) {
         if (res) {
            $scope.data.price = $scope.forfait.price;
            $scope.data.options = JSON.stringify($scope.selected_options);
            $scope.disable_after_send = true;

            requestService.send($scope.data, function (response) {
              console.log('response', response)
              $scope.disable_after_send = false
              if (response.send_to) {

                $ionicPopup.alert({
                  template: "Votre demande à été envoyée - en attente d'un profesionnel",
                  title: 'Demande envoyée'
                })

                $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
                  disableBack: true
                })

                $state.go('app.myrequests')
              } else {
                $ionicPopup.alert({
                  template: "Aucun pro n'est disponible actuellement dans votre zone !",
                  title: "Demande non envoyée"
                })
              }
            })
          }
       })*/
    }

    $scope.getCurrentPosition = function() {
      $ionicLoading.show({
        template: 'localisation...'
      })
      var posOptions = {timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: false}
      $cordovaGeolocation
        .getCurrentPosition(posOptions)
        .then(function (pos) {
          $scope.data.lat = pos.coords.latitude
          $scope.data.lng = pos.coords.longitude
          $scope.initMap()
          $ionicLoading.hide()
        }, function (err) {
          $ionicLoading.hide()
        })
    }

    $scope.subcategories = {}

    $scope.getSubCategories = function (cb) {
      CategoryService.subcats({
        category_id: $stateParams.category
      }, function(response) {
        $scope.subcategories = response
      })

      cb();
    }

    $scope.forfaits = {}

    $scope.getForfaits = function (cb) {
      CategoryService.forfaits({
        sub_category_id: $stateParams.subcategory
      }, function(response) {
        console.log(response)
        $scope.forfaits = response
      })

      cb();
    }

    $scope.forfait = {}
    $scope.options = {}
    $scope.category = {}
    $scope.selected_options = [];

    $scope.toggleOption = function(index, id, selected) {
      if (selected) {
        $scope.selected_options.push(id);
        $scope.forfait.price = parseInt($scope.forfait.price) + parseInt($scope.options[index].price);
      } else {
        var i = $scope.selected_options.indexOf(id);
        if (i > -1) {
          $scope.selected_options.splice(i, 1);
        }
        $scope.forfait.price = parseInt($scope.forfait.price) - parseInt($scope.options[index].price);
      }

      console.log($scope.selected_options);
    }

    $scope.getDetailForfait = function(cb) {
      CategoryService.detail_forfait({
        forfait: $stateParams.forfait
      }, function(response) {
        console.log(response)
        $scope.forfait = response.forfait;
        $scope.options = response.options;
        $scope.category = response.category_id;
      })

      cb();
    }

    $scope.categories = [];

    $scope.getCategories = function (cb) {
      CategoryService.all(function (data) {
        $scope.categories = data;
        /*angular.forEach(data, function(cat) {
          CategoryService.check({
            user_id: $rootScope.profile.id,
            category_id: cat.id
          }, function (response) {
            $ionicLoading.hide()
            if (response.exist) {
              // //console.log("yes")
              cat.exist = true
            } else {
              cat.exist = false
            }
            $scope.categories.push(cat)
            // //console.log(cat)
          })
        })*/
        //console.log($scope.categories)
        cb()
      })
    }
  })
```

Profile Service

```
.service('ProfileService', function ($rootScope, $log, $timeout, $ionicPopup, localStorageService, webService) {
    this.profile = function () {
      return localStorageService.get('profile')
    }

    this.isAuth = function () {
      return this.profile()
    }

    this.online = function (info, cb) {
      $.ajax({
        url: webService.buildUrl('online'),
        method: 'POST',
        data: info,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
          cb(response)
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          $log.error(textStatus)
        }
      })
    };

    this.offline = function (info, cb) {
      $.ajax({
        url: webService.buildUrl('offline'),
        method: 'POST',
        data: info,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
          cb(response)
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          $log.error(textStatus)
        }
      })
    };

    this.updateGeo = function (info, cb) {
      $.ajax({
        url: webService.buildUrl('update_geo'),
        method: 'POST',
        data: info,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
          cb(response)
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          $log.error(textStatus)
        }
      })
    }

    this.updateProfilePicture = function (info, cb) {
      $.ajax({
        url: webService.buildUrl('update_profile_picture'),
        method: 'POST',
        data: info,
        // dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
          cb(response)
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          $log.error(textStatus)
        }
      })
    }

    this.resetPassword = function (info, cb) {
      $.ajax({
        url: webService.buildUrl('reset_password'),
        data: info,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
          cb(response)
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          $log.error(textStatus)
        }
      })
    }

    this.get = function (id, cb) {
      $.ajax({
        url: webService.buildUrl('get_user'),
        data: {
          user_id: id
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
          cb(response)
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          $log.error(textStatus)
        }
      })
    }

    this.validateEmail = function (email) {
      var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
      return re.test(email)
    }

    this.Auth = function (user, cb) {
      $.ajax({
        url: webService.buildUrl('login'),
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: user,
        success: function (data) {
          $log.debug(data)
          if (! data.user) {
            // $log.debug('not logged in')
            cb(false)
          } else {
            // $log.debug('profile in localStorageService')
            localStorageService.set('profile', data.user)
            // $rootScope.unbind = localStorageService.bind($rootScope, 'profile')
            cb(true)
          }
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          $log.error(textStatus + ':' + errorThrown)
        }
      })
    }

    this.logout = function (cb) {
      localStorageService.remove('profile')
      cb()
    }

    this.status = function (info, cb) {
      $.ajax({
        url: webService.buildUrl('state'),
        method: 'POST',
        data: info,
        success: function (data) {
          cb(data)
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          $log.error(textStatus)
        }
      })
    }

    this.type = function (info, cb) {
      console.log(info)
      $.ajax({
        url: webService.buildUrl('type'),
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: info,
        success: function (data) {
          cb(data)
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          $log.error(textStatus)
        }
      })
    }

    this.update = function (user, cb) {
      $.ajax({
        url: webService.buildUrl('update'),
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: user,
        success: function (data) {
          cb(data)
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          $log.error(textStatus)
        }
      })
    }

    this.updatePassword = function (info, cb) {
      $.ajax({
        url: webService.buildUrl('update_password'),
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: info,
        success: function (data) {
          cb(data)
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          $log.error(textStatus)
        }
      })
    }

    this.register = function (user, cb) {
      $.ajax({
        url: webService.buildUrl('register'),
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: user,
        success: function (data) {
          cb(data)
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          $log.error(textStatus)
        }
      })
    }

    this.switchMode = function (mode) {
      // $log.debug('switchMode: ' + mode)
      // $log.debug('profile id: ' + this.profile().id)
      $.ajax({
        url: webService.buildUrl('changemode'),
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
          user_id: this.profile().id,
          type: mode
        },
        success: function (data) {
          // $log.debug(data)
          if (data) {
            localStorageService.set('profile', data)
          }
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          $log.error(textStatus)
        }
      })
    }
  })
```

Cordova CLI: 6.1.1
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.1
Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.1
Ionic Framework Version: 1.3.1
Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.16
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.7.3
OS: Node Version: v4.4.4

I'm using:
ionic bundle 1.3.1
angularjs v1.5.8

Comment: i too faced this once.....try with $location.path here.

Comment: Can you post a piace of code? When this error happen means that you pass to a function a var instead of a function (for example in a callback)

Comment: i added the controller and the profile service to my post

Comment: please help me, i'm stack with this bug one week